# JQuery find and update attribute of child element then return the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string representing a checkbox such as follows:

```
var checkbox = "<div class="text-center"><label for="cb_1"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_1"/></label></div>";
```

I want to make the checkbox checked (add the attribute checked="checked") such that the string becomes:

```
<div class="text-center"><label for="cb_1"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_1" checked="checked"/></label></div>;
```

I have tried the following:

```
$(checkbox).find('input').attr('checked', true).end().html();
```

This return the following:

```
<label for="cb_1"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_1" checked="checked"/></label>
```

My question is why is the first div not returned and how can I return the whole thing like:

```
<div class="text-center"><label for="cb_1"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_1" checked="checked"/></label></div>;
```

Comment: Working with HTML as a string is a bit of a code smell. Is it not added to the DOM at some point at which you can then update the properties of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html()` in jquery uses `innerHTML` property. In this case, `outerHTML` need to be used, So

Try using [`prop('outerHTML')`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
var checkbox = '<div class="text-center"><label for="cb_1"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_1"/></label></div>';

console.log($(checkbox).find('input').attr('checked', true).end().prop('outerHTML'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Reference**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$($(checkbox).find('input').attr('checked', true).end().parentNode).html();
```